# Bulleted List Styling in Outlook HTML Emails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am running into a very unique issue in outlook emails. Following all advice I have converted my html lists to tables, that resemble something similar to the below code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="font-size:13px;font-family:'Courier New',Courier,monospace;">
            <td valign="top" style="padding-right:3px;padding-left: 40px;">•</td>
            <td valign="top">Sample Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-size:13px;font-family:'Courier New',Courier,monospace;">
            <td valign="top" style="padding-right:3px;padding-left: 40px;">•</td>
            <td valign="top">Sample Text #2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is displaying correctly in Web Browsers but in any version of Outlook an extra space is getting added before the first bullet. After some analysis I found that the Outlook html looked something like this:

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='mso-cellspacing:0in;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
        <td valign=top style='padding:0in 2.25pt 0in 30.0pt'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>
                <span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>
                    <span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span>
                </span>
                <span style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:"Courier New";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>•<o:p></o:p></span>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
            <p class=MsoNormal>
                <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Courier New"; mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Sample Text<o:p></o:p></span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
...
```

You will see to the left of the bullet there is this tag:

```
<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span>
```

Outlook seems to be adding a space. Does anyone know why this is? Is there anyway for me to stop this or ignore this tag?

NOTE: This only happens in certain cases not every case, and always only on the first bullet. There is NO difference between the cases where it does, and does not happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One big issue in my experience is that padding left and right isn't rendered (or not correctly) in outlook

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of solving this is to select the span based on it's attribute and set it to zero size. In this way only when this  tag is present it will be styled

```
span[style|=mso-spacerun]
  {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ok sorry to hear, let me know if I can help further, It's just that I don't have outlook and couldn't test it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. Outlook was actually comlaining of a Block Element being iside an inline element:

```
<pre>
    ...
    <table>...</table>
    ...
</pre>
```

I guess outlook does not enjoy block elements inside of inline elements.